# VBA: if value a in cell matches value in cell b then copy cell C to cell D

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on the automisation of a workbook and I can't seem to fix the next thing. What I want to do:

If the values in column A of worksheet3 matches the values in column A of worksheet7 then copy the value of column K of worksheet7 to column L in worksheet3.

Does anybody knows the code? Tried several things on Google, but I can't seem to find what I exactly need.

Answer (score 2):

Try to split your problem into smaller pieces and then solve them one at a time. If there is a specific step which fails, then ask in here. You problem looks something like this:

- Get the value of column A in worksheet 3 and 7
- Check if values are identical
- If yes: Copy from ws7 column K to ws3 column L
- Loop the above for all rows

Now you have four steps to solve. There are many ways to do this, and I am not going to code it for you. But it should not be difficult to find a solution to any of them.